# Deleting a specific number in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am running into a problem in my code. I have an Arraylist, and I have a bunch of zeros that I need to remove. They are mixed in with other numbers, which I want to keep. However, when I do a for loop, it will skip over some zeros and won't remove them. Here my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
     ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
     while(scan.hasNextLine()){
         list.add(scan.nextDouble());
     }

     for(int i=1; i<list.size();i+=4){
         if(list.get(i)<150000){
             list.set(i-1,(double) 0);
             list.set(i,(double) 0);
             list.set(i+1,(double) 0);
             list.set(i+2,(double) 0);
         }
     }

     for(int i=2; i<list.size();i+=4){
         if(list.get(i)>22.2){
             list.set(i-2,(double) 0);
             list.set(i-1,(double) 0);
             list.set(i,(double) 0);
             list.set(i+1,(double) 0);
         }
     }

     for(int i=3; i<list.size();i+=4){
         if(list.get(i)<1100){
             list.set(i-3,(double) 0);
             list.set(i-2,(double) 0);
             list.set(i-1,(double) 0);
             list.set(i,(double) 0);
         }
     }

     for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         if(list.get(i)==0){
             list.remove(i);
         }
     }

     System.out.println(list);
 }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't post it as link. Post some relevant code here.

Comment: Always add code in your question itself

Comment: I can not see the code but try to run the loop backwards.

Comment: post your input.txt content here

Comment: Voting to close as MCVE which includes input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You are structurally modifying the list while you remove the 0's. Use an iterator

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   int elem = iterator.next(); 
   if (elem == 0)
     iterator.remove();
}
```

Hope it helps.
PD: You can include code directly in the question text using the "{}" button

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about it before I went to sleep and used a nested for loop. This code looks a lot cleaner though!

Answer (score 0):

This is you problem:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
   if(list.get(i)==0)
   {
      list.remove(i);
   }
}
```

Look, let's say, you found `0` value at `i=2`. You removing item with index 2. All list items, that was after 2 item will shift up. So, 3 item will become 2, 4 will become 3 and so on. But you incrementing `i` and skiping next (shifted up) item.

You have keep index if you found `0` value and increment it else:

```
int i=0;
while(i<i<list.size()){
    if(list.get(i)==0){
       list.remove(i);
    }else{
       i++;
    }
}
```